split / process ".data" by groups
I want to add group-wise labels using geom_text based on the magical .data object. However, because .data is a "pronoun", I cant split it or even identify it's names. What is the best way to split .data by group (i.e. here: facet * colour = 6 total groups) so that I can add a unique label per-group?
The MWE below is simplified a lot from my actual code; I need to use .data so please don't suggest to mutate X before the ggplot.
library('ggplot2')

set.seed(0)
n = 900
X = data.frame(i=1:n,a=1:3,b=4:5)
X$y = runif(n,X$a,X$b)

fun = function(.df){
  rep(1:6,n/6)
}

g = ggplot(X,aes(y=y,colour=factor(b))) +
  geom_text(aes(y=0,x=0,label=fun(.data)),check_overlap=TRUE) +
  facet_grid('~a') +
  geom_boxplot()
print(g)


"I need to use .data...": I fear this may be an XY problem.

Can you update your question to be more similar to your actual problem? It's hard to understand your issue with the current example

Also are you trying to label each data point or the boxplots? Your fun currently returns 900 elements

Not clear to me why you need the .data pronoun. As you want a unique id per combo of the variable mapped on color and the facetting variable you can do so using the interaction of these variables:
library("ggplot2")

set.seed(0)
n <- 900
X <- data.frame(i = 1:n, a = 1:3, b = 4:5)
X$y <- runif(n, X$a, X$b)

ggplot(X, aes(y = y, colour = factor(b))) +
  geom_text(
    aes(y = 0, x = 0, label = as.numeric(interaction(a, b))),
    check_overlap = TRUE,
    position = position_dodge(.75)
  ) +
  facet_grid("~a") +
  geom_boxplot()



Thanks. 2 things that are more complex in my non-MWE: 1) the label value is actually a function of multiple columns; 2) I don't want to pre-suppose to know the grouping variables as I am writing a function that aims to support arbitrary aes(...). Hence using .data
